# How to use IF or ELSE statements in Python? BTW, How is my username and profile picture?

Tags: python

I want to write a function that takes number between 1 and 7 as a parameter and prints out the corresponding day as a string.

For example, if the parameter is 1, your function should print out `one`. If the parameter is 2, your function should print out `two`, etc.

I wrote this program, but I am not getting anything as an output. I sure that I am using the `if` and `else` statements correctly

My program:

```
def string(x):
  if x=="1":
      word = "one"
  else:
      if x=="2":
        word = "two"
    else:
        if x=="3":
            word = "three"
        else:
            if x=="4":
                word = "four"
            else:
                if x=="5":
                    word = "five"
                else:
                    if x=="6":
                        word = "six"
                    else:
                          if x=="7":
                              word = "seven"
                          else:
                              word = "Try again"
return word

def main():
  y = int(input("Please enter a number between 1 and 7: "))
  z = string(y)
  print(z)

main()
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/controlflow.html

Comment: I think you are looking for else if:

Comment: I read that already. Can you tell me what is the problem with my program? It is not printing anything if I enter an input.

Comment: Also, you're getting the input, changing it to an `int`, then sending it to a function that expects a string.

Comment: You mean remove the `input`?

Comment: No, just remove the `int()` call that surrounds it. I'll write it up as an answer with some more suggestions.

Comment: It works now, but why doesn't it work if I insert `int`?

Comment: Because you are comparing your variable against a character. You could also have changed the comparison to if x==1 rather than "1"

Comment: `1` is not the same as `'1'`. The former is a number, the latter is a string. `1 + 1` is `2`, but `'1' + '1'` is `'11'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do in this case is remove the `int()` call from the `main()`. Your `string()` function is expecting a string - if you send it an `int`, it'll never work. Additionally, you can use the `elif` keyword:

```
def string(x):
    if x=="1":
        word = "one"
    elif x=="2":
        word = "two"
    elif x=="3":
        word = "three"
    elif x=="4":
        word = "four"
    elif x=="5":
        word = "five"
    elif x=="6":
        word = "six"
    elif x=="7":
        word = "seven"
    else:
        word = "Try again"
    return word

def main():
  y = input("Please enter a number between 1 and 7: ")
  z = string(y)
  print(z)

main()
```

Or you can use a data structure called a `dictionary`:

```
def string(x):
    if x not in ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'):
        return "Try again"

    d = {'1':'one', '2':'two', '3':'three', '4':'four',
    '5':'five', '6':'six', '7':'seven'}

    return d.get(x)

def main():
  print(string(input("Please enter a number between 1 and 7: ")))

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you're taking an input which will be a string, then casting it to an int and trying to compare it to strings, so either take out the int() conversion or change your if statements to compare against integers.

Secondly whilst your if statements will work, you should be using if, elseif, etc.

Thirdly it's much better to use switch statements for multiple comparisons. Even better, a dictionary

With elseifs:

```
def string(x):
   if x=="1":
       word = "one"
   elif x=="2":
       word = "two"
   elif x=="3":
       word = "three"
   elif x=="4":
       word = "four"
   elif x=="5":
       word = "five"
   elif x=="6":
       word = "six"
   elif x=="7":
       word = "seven"
   else
       word = "Try again"

   return word
```

With dictionary:

```
intWordLookup = {1:"one",
                 2:"two",
                 3:"three",
                 4:"four",
                 5:"five",
                 6:"six",
                 7:"seven"}

def main():
   y = int(input("Please enter a number between 1 and 7: "))
   z = intWordLookup[y]
   print(z)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def string(x):
    if x == "1":
        word = "one"
    elif x == "2":
        word = "two"
    elif x == "3":
        word = "three"
    elif x == "4":
        word = "four"
    elif x == "5":
        word = "five"
    elif x == "6":
        word == "six"
    elif x == "7":
        word == "seven"
    else:
        word == "try again"
    return word

x = input("Enter a number: ")
z = string(x)
print(z)
```

you don't have to convert the user input to an int then back to a string because its a string already.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate approach using built in zip function.

```
list_num=list(range(1,8))
list_words=['one','two','three','four','five','six','seven']
myArray=zip(list_words,list_num)
def somefunc(x):
    take_inp=input("Enter any number between 1 and 7:")
    if take_inp in list_num:
        return myArray[take_inp -1][0]
    else:
        print "Try Again"

print somefunc()
```